# Element Incorrectly Positioned on Page Until Window Resized

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

I have a webpage containing several Divs which contain individual 'pages'. I have defined the following CSS styles:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.hideDiv{
    display:none;
}

.showDiv{
    display: inline;
}
```

Everything worked fine and for a long while we had no problems either viewing our pages in Safari on our Macs or in IE6 (which our client uses).

We then updated Safari from 4.0.5 and we suddenly had page elements initially appearing incorrectly positioned. The first page is OK but when you click 'Next' an image positioned to the right of the layout appears initially offset considerably to the right mostly outside its containing Div clipping most of the image. However as soon as I resize the window the image jumps into it's correct position. If you click from say page 2 to page 3 and then click back again to page 2, so the image has been cached, it displays correctly.

We painfully downgraded Safari on some Macs and soldiered on with others hoping an update would fix it. Curiously everything works well on my new Mac Pro running Safari 6. The pages always display fine in IE6. My MacBook Pro running Safari 5.1.7 always offsets the images.

I don't believe it is a Browser issue but an area of my code which isn't very robust and some Browsers don't interpret the code as we would want it.

I created fresh html files which are identical to the multi-div page but contain only one 'page'. The layout is solid every time I display it in Safari 5.1.7 so I don't think it is my html/CSS which defines the position of the element. Here is a typical Div containing a single 'page':

```
<!-- Page 1 -->
<div class="showDiv clear" id="page1">

    <div id="bgPic-components">

        <!-- Sub-Heading -->
        <h1>Sub-Heading</span></h1>

        <!-- Page Content Area -->
        <div class="contentTextArea fullWidth">

            <div style="position:absolute; width:280px; z-index:2;">
                <p>Some body text here.</p>
            </div>

            <table style="position:absolute; right:40px; bottom:40px; z-index:0;">
                <tr><td>
                    <img src="../../medialibrary/3DI/3DI0315.02.01.jpg" style="display:block; position:relative; height:440px;"/>
                    <p class="padCaption">Annotation</p>
                </td></tr>
            </table>

            <table style="position:absolute; bottom:24px; z-index:0;">
            <tr><td>
                <img src="../../medialibrary/photographs/P0825.01.01.jpg" alt="" style="display:block; position:relative; height:300px"/>
                <p class="padCaption">Annotation</p>
            </td></tr>
        </table>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I would be very grateful for any suggestions to help me narrow down and find the problem.

Regards

Chris

Comment: Could you create an example of the multi-page problem in JSFiddle or somewhere similar? It would be useful to try it out.

Comment: Try to add `zoom: 1;` to your `showDiv` div. Also, did you tried `display: block` instead of `display: inline`?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I'm getting closer. Any element positioned using 'Left' or 'Top' is reliably positioned correctly. The right and bottom edges are not reliably defined when the div is set to 'inline'.

Comment: I might suggest using display: inline-block; it kind of combines the best of both worlds :)

Comment: Thank you Tammy. I have narrowed the problem down and this is what I think is happening: When a Div's display is set to be 'inline', from 'none', any images within with a CSS 'right' or 'Bottom' can only be positioned if the width and height are known. The browser can't seem to establish the width and height and so assumes 0 pixels. The images appear at the correct size but the browser is positioning the left edge where the right edge should be because it thinks the image has a width of 0 pixels so the browser assumes the right edge is 0 pixels from the left edge. The same is true for height.

Comment: I would love to answer your question but I'll have to see all the related CSS definitions you apply. I would expect something like this Fiddle I set up for you... http://jsfiddle.net/JmbtP/

Comment: Thanks Korijn. I will try and develop a very simple prototype which replicates the problem and which I can share. It will be very similar to your fiddle but within the second page is a div defining the area which the content must fit and within that an image with CSS right 20px. The width/height of the image isn't specified in the CSS. Try it and see if you get the same results.